# How to write function / code to switch between two text ? Language learning app. So Language 1 to Language 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

I made an app for learning Japanese language.
So When we click on the button it will change the label.text = "English" to Label.text = "Japanese" I use the if function as below.

```
 @IBAction func datingButtonPressed1(_ sender: UIButton) {
       if datingLabel01.text == "Anata ga suki desu. 
      - あなた　が　すき　です" { 
          datingLabel01.text = "I like you." 
}else { 
   datingLabel01.text = "Anata ga suki desu. - あなた　が　すき　です" 
}
```

I have 15 words and phrases for each categories so I already had to create 150 IB Actions and labels and so .
picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpnRP.png)

Now my question is :

What is the better way to do this ?

The app link is :

https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/learn-japanese/id1528287144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to structure your translations in some kind of data model. A sample approach could look like this :

```
class Translation {
    private let en: String
    private let jp: String

    var isEnglishDisplayed = true
    
    var currentText: String {
        return isEnglishDisplayed ? en : jp
    }

    init(en: String, jp: String) { 
        self.en = en
        self.jp = jp
    }
}
```

And then you can have some kind of factory creating lists of these objects :

```
class TranslationCategories {

    // Returns an array of `Translation` objects for `General` category
    static func getGeneralCategory() -> [Translation] {
        return [
            Translation(en: "Translation", jp: "翻訳 - Hon'yaku"),
            // Other elements of category
        ]
    }

}
```

Then, in your view controller, you can get rid of all the `IBActions` for each of the cells, and use `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods to set your data, something similar to this :

```
privat evar translations: [Translation] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.translations = TranslationCategoriews.getGeneralCategory()
}


func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ : UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
    return translations.count
}

func tableView(_ : UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // dequeue cell as needed
    cell.text = self.translations[indexPath.row].currentText

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let translation = translations[indePath.row]
    translation.isEnglishDisplayed.toggle()

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell.text = translation.currentText
}
```

---

This is heavily simplified, just to show the general idea of the approach. You may need to adjust it more or less, depending on the current state of your code as a whole.

Things not covered by this sample :

- Figuring out how to choose which category to get from `TranslationCategories` based on which one user selected
- Figuring out how to use the buttons, instead of selecting entire cell

These are left as an excercise to the reader since they depend more on the entire approach.

To sum up :

- You need some form of data model that will enable you to structure your data
- You need to adjust your view controller to make use of this structured data, instead of using static texts and dedicated methods for each row

---

This of course is not the "only" way or "the best" way. Its just a proposition on how to solve the issue presented in the question.

Comment: You are amazing ! thank you